# Create database if already exists using QUOTENAME

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};"
    "SERVER="+server+";"
    "UID="+username+";"
    "PWD="+password,
    autocommit=True)

cursor = conn.cursor()

database= "abcd"
sql_create = (
        "DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);"
        "SET @sql = 'if not exists(select * from sys.databases where name = ' + QUOTENAME(?) + ')'  + ' CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(?);"
        "EXEC sp_executesql @sql")
cursor.execute(sql_create,database,database)
```

#### Getting error msg like pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', u"[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'abcd'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")"

Comment: Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question. Why did you tag python-3 and python-2 - are you really using both? I removed all the other tags because you _might_ use those techs but your question is pure sql and totally independent from those other tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `QUOTENAME` and concatenation for the `WHERE` clause parameter. Also, avoid using the legacy `SQL Server` ODBC driver that ships with Windows to access Azure SQL Database. Instead, download and use a [newer ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). Below is an example with these changes.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
    "SERVER="+server+";"
    "UID="+username+";"
    "PWD="+password,
    autocommit=True)

cursor = conn.cursor()

database= "abcd"
sql_create = (
        "DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);"
        "SET @sql = N'if not exists(select * from sys.databases where name = @DatabaseName)'  + N' CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(?) + N';';"
        "EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@DatabaseName sysname', @DatabaseName = ?;")
cursor.execute(sql_create,database,database)
```

You could also declare a T-SQL variable for the database name and assign it to the parameter value so that you only need to pass a single parameter:

```
sql_create = (
        "DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);"
        "DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname = ?;"
        "SET @sql = N'if not exists(select * from sys.databases where name = @DatabaseName)'  + N' CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + N';';"
        "EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@DatabaseName sysname', @DatabaseName = @DatabaseName;")
cursor.execute(sql_create,database)
```

Comment: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')  Getting this error

Comment: @sumitsalunke, I added the `@DatabaseName` parameter to the `sp_executesql` along with another example.